# Button inside fragment

Tags: android, button, fragment

I'm hoping someone can help me with this extremely annoying problem. I'm new to working with fragments. I've have spend two days trying to get buttons to work inside my fragment. My app is a tab activity with sliding fragments auto created by android studio. I can change fragments by sliding and using the tabs. But I cannot get the buttons to respond. My app does not crash and my `Log.e` doesn't get registered in `Logcat`. I have copied lots of examples from the internet, but nothing seems to work.

I have tried implementing `View.OnClickListener` and not implementing it but nothing works. I'll post two examples that should work, but they don't.

FRAGMENT without implementing `View.OnClickListener`

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summary_loggs, container, false);
     Button test = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.testButton);
    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.e("DEBUGG", "BUTTON PRESSED");
        }
    });
    return rootView;
```

FRAGMENT with implementing `View.OnClickListener`

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summary_loggs, container, false);
     Button test = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.testButton);
    test.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootView;
}

    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.testButton:
            Log.e("DEBUGG", "BUTTON PRESSED");
            break;

    }
}
```

This is only two examples of many that I have tried and it is driving me crazy. On all the examples on internet they all get them to work. My buttons simply won't respond when I press them. I will be extremely thankful if you could help me with this.

Layoutfile

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="xxxxxx.SummaryLoggs">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test"
        android:id="@+id/testButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
 </FrameLayout>
```

ACTIVITY where i swipe fragments view

```
import...

public class AmLogger extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {


    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    Handler customHandler = new Handler();

   ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_am_logger);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {

            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_am_logger, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {        
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }
        private int mPosition;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               mPosition = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);   
           Log.e("DEBUGG", "mPosition: " + mPosition);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summary_loggs, container, false);

            switch (mPosition) {
                case 1:
                   rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_time, container, false);
                    break;
                case 2:
                   rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);
                    break;
              }
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging or showing a simple `Toast`? Perhaps there's something wrong with your Logcat output and your button works?

Comment: Hi. Yes i just need to implement a button to  the fragment. But the buttons wont work. yes i have also tried to use a toast. that dosnt work either.

Comment: @user1512762 Please show your fragment layout file also.

Comment: I have also tried using toast. And logcat is working on other projects i have. :)

Comment: @user1512762 What is your layout file name? Is your fragment class implementing **View.OnClickListener**?

Comment: Show where you are putting your Fragments inside your Activity.

Comment: @user1512762 I think I understood your problem, to provide you with necessary info please let me know how many fragments are there in your Activity and also in which fragment do you want to put the button? Please mention the **Fragment names**, it'll help me to solve the issue.

Comment: i have three fragments, (one for each tab). The names of the fragments are AddTime, MyLoggs and SummaryLogs. i want the button on SummaryLogs fragment. The layout names are (in the same order), fragment_add_time, fragment_item_list and fragment_summary_loggs.

Comment: Do you also have **PlaceholderFragment** ? Can you update your Activity file and post entire code (Not the import statements though). It seems very confusing to me.

Comment: Why is the **rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summary_loggs, container, false);** missing inside your switch statement? You need to have 3 cases, one for each tab right?

Comment: yes i though so too.  but then it would not show. this way all three fragments are showing on each tab. I have also tried to put buttons on the other fragments but that didnt work either.

Comment: @prudhvi perhaps im calling the switching to new fragment wrong?

Comment: Where are your 3 fragment classes in the Activity code you posted just now?

Comment: I posted the entire activity code. Do i need to add something to the activity?

Comment: For each tab, you are just returning the same **PlaceholderFragment** instead of 3 different fragments. That is why you can't see the button. Let me add the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not creating 3 fragments. You should have 3 fragment classes in your activity one for each tab and also depending upon design for each fragment, you need to have 3 layout files. Then declare the button in your appropriate layout file and use it in your Fragment class as shown below.

```
public class AmLogger extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {


    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    Handler customHandler = new Handler();

    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_am_logger);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {@Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {

            actionBar.addTab(
            actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_am_logger, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {}

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {}

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    // AddTime fragment
                    return AddTime.newInstance(position + 1);
                case 1:
                    // MyLogs fragment
                    return MyLogs.newInstance(position + 1);
                case 2:
                    // SummaryLogs fragment
                    return SummaryLogs.newInstance(position + 1);
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    //AddTime fragment
    public static class AddTime extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";


        public static AddTime newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            AddTime fragment = new AddTime();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public AddTime() {}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_addtime, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    //MyLogs Fragment
    public static class MyLogs extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public static MyLogs newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            MyLogs fragment = new MyLogs();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public MyLogs() {}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mylogs, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    //SummaryLogs fragment
    public static class SummaryLogs extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public static SummaryLogs newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            SummaryLogs fragment = new SummaryLogs();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public SummaryLogs() {}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summarylogs, container, false);
            //Code to get the button from layout file
            Button btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.testButton);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //Implement the code to run on button click here
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! this works. Although the buttons dont work if i add the code inside the fragment. Only if i add the code in the activity under each fragment section. I thought i could add the button code inside the fragment file. Anyway, your answer works! thank you!